# Apply composer patch from a required composer module

Tags: magento2, patches, composer, magento-framework

I wonder how and if it is possible to apply a patch or if there's any other solution to modify the `magento/framework` from a required composer package.

### Patch successfully applied.

The following patch is successfully applied when added to the project's composer.json.

**composer.json:**

```json
"extra": {
    "patches": {
      "magento/framework": {
        "Custom Patch": "https://urltopatch/patch.patch"
      }
    }
  },
```

**Patch:**

```json
diff --git a/View/Layout/etc/elements.xsd b/View/Layout/etc/elements.xsd
index 17857c9ab06..516ba6d00cd 100644
--- a/View/Layout/etc/elements.xsd
+++ b/View/Layout/etc/elements.xsd
@@ -119,7 +119,7 @@
 
     <xs:simpleType name="htmlClassType">
         <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
-            <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d\-_]*(\s[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d\-_]*)*"/>
+            <xs:pattern value="[@a-zA-Z][@a-zA-Z\d\-_]*(\s[@a-zA-Z][@a-zA-Z\d\-_]*)*"/>
         </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleType>
```

### Patch doesn't get applied.

However the patch doesn't get applied when it's configured in a required composer package such as below:

**Project composer.json:**

```json
{
    "name": "maxserv/magento2-community-edition",
    "require": {
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.5-p2",
        "custom/magento-theme-framework"
    },
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

**Module's composer.json:**

```json
{
  "name": "custom/magento-theme-framework",
  "require": {
    "magento/framework": "*",
    "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.7"
  },
  "extra": {
    "patches": {
      "magento/framework": {
        "Custom Patch": "https://urltopatch/patch.patch"
      }
    }
  },
}
```

### Question

Are there any solutions to modify the code of `magento/framework` from a submodule, so that the code automatically gets modified after installing a submodule?

Comment: why would you want this? you should never touch the Magento core files, unless you are applying an official Magento patch.

Comment: @DianaBotean we would like to allow special characters such as @ to the container HtmlClass attribute which is not possible due to Magento's current restrictions. I've seen at least 2 issues addressing this but late to no responses from the Magento Developers. This way we would like to reduce restrictions sooner without having to apply a patch for every single project separately.

Comment: I see, but tbh, I would still advise against it and try to find other ways to achieve this. wish you good luck!

Comment: @KoendeBont have u found the way? I don't agree that you can't apply your patches. Sometimes you HAVE TO do it and this way is much better than e.g peformance by di.xml.